# Enable show on mobile version?

Tags: html, css, html.dropdownlistfor

It looks like my code disables show on mobile version.
I have been writing some code that adds an arrow into a dropdownlist option bar. Google Chrome works just fine, but the mobile version does not display, is anything wrong?

Can take a look from your mobile also: [Screen shot of desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqRPE.png)

```css
.selectdiv {
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
}
 
/*To remove button from IE11, thank you Matt */
select::-ms-expand {
     display: none;
}
 
.selectdiv:after {
  content: '>';
  font: 20px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 11px;
   display: inline;
  /*Adjust for position however you want*/
  
  top: 18px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  /*left line */
  
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 
.selectdiv select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Add some styling */
   display: inline;

}
```

Comment: Try changing the position attribute of the after element; I'm unable to test it on mobile, but the issue occurs in safari 11.1.2 too and can be fixed after changing position and recalculating relevant css

Comment: The issue is with .selectdiv position sticky; adding -webkit-sticky works

Comment: Added -webkit-sticky aldy, but still not work for IOS, for android sometimes showing only...